# How can I test against a query executing without errors within a transaction?

Tags: coldfusion, transactions, coldfusion-9

I'm running two queries within a ColdFusion transaction (ColdFusion 9, MySQL 5):

```
private boolean function updates()
{
    transaction
    {
        local.foo = new Query();
        local.foo.setSql("UPDATE foo SET bar = foo");
        local.foo.execute();

        local.bar = new Query();
        local.bar.setSql("UPDATE bar SET foo = bar");
        local.bar.execute();
    }

    if (both updates were successful)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would like to know the following: What should I replace `both updates where successful` in the `if()` with to test if the queries executed correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution swallows the errors, and leaves it to the calling function to examine and rethrow them.  As such, I changed your return value on you.  It's a struct with a boolean and an error array.

```
local.result.bool = false;
local.result.error = ArrayNew(1);
TRANSACTION action="begin" 
{
 try{
    local.foo = new Query();
    local.foo.setSql("UPDATE foo SET bar = foo");
    local.foo.execute();
    local.bar = new Query();
    local.bar.setSql("UPDATE bar SET foo = bar");
    local.bar.execute();
 }
 catch(any excpt){
    ArrayAppend(local.result.error, excpt);
 }finally{
   if(ArrayLen(local.result.error) gt 0){
      transactionRollback();
    }else{
      local.result.bool = true; 
    }
 } 
}
return local.result;
```

Comment: Disclaimer - I am away from my coldfusion 9 environment, i hope i have that exactly right...

Comment: thanks for that. I will use this, but I need to get rid of the Array(). Unfortunately it is necessary that the function returns boolean since another function depends on the result being boolean. I'm not concerned about the errors showing up. Rather, only for the transaction!

Comment: If you *really* wanted to swallow the error (not sure why), just return the boolean value at the end. But either way, a single try/catch should do it.

Comment: @leigh agreed, i went overboard with try/catches